# How to correct errors from Lyx

Tags: lyx

I have been using Lyx to edit documents, and after changing the Document Class, I Lyx complains of errors when I try to render a preview (PDF) ...

[image]

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

I am not certain this the the correct place ... but anyways ... I can't edit the source of Lyx?

```
\hline 
$e^{f(x)}$ & $f'(x)\cdot e^{f(x)}$\tabularnewline
\hline 
$ln(f(x))$ & 
\[
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
\]
\tabularnewline
\hline
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (respectively not working) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: >"changing the Document Class": Do you use another document class than before (old one/new one?), or did you change the code of the used class (original code/changed code?)?

Comment: @Stephen, I originally used Lyx with another document class "SGML" (if I'm not wrong) then I changed to another like article. I don't have a problem if I revert my Document Class

Comment: I don't know much about LyX, but `\[...\]` is *not* allowed in `l`, `c` or `r` columns. In order to get a "big fraction", write `$\displaystyle\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$` or, if **amsmath** has been loaded, `$\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$`.

Comment: I think egreg is right (as usual). When his comment solved your problem, please state so here and ask egreg to re-post his comment as answer, thus that it can be marked as accepted answer (and thereby the question as solved).

Comment: Yes you are right ... its about using display style fractions in tables ... Lyx doesn't appear to know how to fix that ... worse ... it doesn't allow editing of code easily ... from what I found, I need to export a tex file then edit ... or not use display style fractions in tables

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about LyX, but `\[...\]` is not allowed in `l`, `c` or `r` columns of a `tabular` environment.

In order to get a "big fraction", write

```
$\displaystyle\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$
```

or, if amsmath has been loaded,

```
$\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$
```